# A Bouncing Ball Canvas Program

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've just completed reading [the game tutorial of w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/games/default.asp) and wrote a piece of code from scratch.

This program basically creates a canvas element with a ball bouncing off the walls of the canvas. The user can also control the ball using arrow keys. I'm planning to make this into a small game by creating some obstacles etc

```js
var gameRun;
var ball;

function startGame() {
    gameObj.start();

    ball = new component(100, 100, 0, 0, "http://www.bit-101.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/ball.png");

    gameRun = setInterval(updateStuff, 10);

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        gameObj.key = e.keyCode;
    });
    window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        gameObj.key = false;
    });
}

var gameObj = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    /*ctx : this.canvas.getContext("2d"),*/
    start : function() {
        document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);

        this.canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
        this.canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
    },
    clear : function() {
        var ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
};

var UR = 1, /* Up-Right   */
    DR = 2, /* Down-Right */
    DL = 3, /* Down-Left  */
    UL = 4; /* Up-Left    */

function component(x, y, width, height, img) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.direction = getRandomInt(1, 4); /* At the start, choose a random direction */

    if(img != undefined) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    this.update = function() {
        var ctx = gameObj.canvas.getContext("2d");
        if(img != undefined) {
            this.image = new Image();
            this.image.src = img;

            this.width = this.image.width;
            this.height = this.image.height;

            ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y);
        }
        else {
            /* TODO: Obstacle creation */
        }
    };

    this.newPos = function() {
        if(img != undefined) {
            if(this.x == 0) {
                if(this.direction == UL) {
                    this.direction = UR;
                }
                else if(this.direction == DL) {
                    this.direction = DR;
                }
            }
            else if(this.x + this.width == gameObj.canvas.width)
            {
                if(this.direction == UR) {
                    this.direction = UL;
                }
                else if(this.direction == DR) {
                    this.direction = DL;
                }
            }
            if(this.y == 0) {
                if(this.direction == UL) {
                    this.direction = DL;
                }
                else if(this.direction == UR) {
                    this.direction = DR;
                }
            }
            else if(this.y + this.height == gameObj.canvas.height)
            {
                if(this.direction == DR) {
                    this.direction = UR;
                }
                else if(this.direction == DL) {
                    this.direction = UL;
                }
            }

            if(this.direction == UL) {
                this.x--;
                this.y--;
            }
            else if(this.direction == UR) {
                this.x++;
                this.y--;
            }
            else if(this.direction == DL) {
                this.x--;
                this.y++;
            }
            else /* this.direction == DR */{
                this.x++;
                this.y++;
            } 
        }
        else {
            /* TODO: Obstacle creation */
        } 
    }
}

function updateStuff() {
    gameObj.clear();
    if      (gameObj.key && gameObj.key == 37) {  /* LEFT  */
        if     (ball.direction == UR) { ball.direction = UL; }
        else if(ball.direction == DR) { ball.direction = DL; }
    }
    else if (gameObj.key && gameObj.key == 39) {  /* RIGHT */
        if     (ball.direction == UL) { ball.direction = UR; }
        else if(ball.direction == DL) { ball.direction = DR; }
    }
    else if (gameObj.key && gameObj.key == 38) {  /* UP    */
        if     (ball.direction == DL) { ball.direction = UL; }
        else if(ball.direction == DR) { ball.direction = UR; }
    }
    else if (gameObj.key && gameObj.key == 40) {  /* DOWN  */
        if     (ball.direction == UR) { ball.direction = DR; }
        else if(ball.direction == UL) { ball.direction = DL; }
    }
    ball.newPos();
    ball.update();
}

/**
 * Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive)
 */
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="startGame()"></body>
```

Before I proceed for further development of the game, I want to get a review of my code.

---

Side note:

Why can't I use

```
ctx : this.canvas.getContext("2d")
```

in `gameObj`? It gives me

> TypeError: this.canvas is undefined

Comment: On the last note, you can't use it because, when defining your object, `this.canvas` is undefined, being a property of this, the window

Comment: So, `this` refers to the `window` object, and not the `gameObj` object? That explains the error? What about the fix? Wrap it in a function like: `ctx : function() { return this.canvas.getContext("2d"); }`?

Comment: that should work if you want `ctx` as a function; wrapping the entire code in a window listener (`window.addEventListener("load", function(){...}`) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I personally would avoid hard-coding all the directions and if-statements to check for them. Instead, what is more efficient is to use just 2 variables, x-velocity and y-velocity. This makes collisions much easier:

```
// I'm using <= and >= just in case you decide to
// make the ball move faster later
if(this.x <= 0 || this.x + this.width >= gameObj.canvas.width)
{
    this.xvel *= -1;
}
if(this.y <= 0 || this.y + this.height >= gameObj.canvas.height)
{
    this.yvel *= -1;
}
```

And movement as well:

```
this.x += xvel;
this.y += yvel;
```

And input is nothing more than setting the value:

```
if      (gameObj.key && gameObj.key == 37) {  /* LEFT  */
    ball.xvel = -1;
}
else if (gameObj.key && gameObj.key == 39) {  /* RIGHT */
    ball.xvel = 1;
}
else if (gameObj.key && gameObj.key == 38) {  /* UP    */
    ball.yvel = -1;
}
else if (gameObj.key && gameObj.key == 40) {  /* DOWN  */
    ball.yvel = 1;
}
```

Good luck with your game!

Comment: Awesome! This would make the code much easier to read and also shortens the code! Thanks!